# tag to create a description field

Tags: html

i want to create a drop down box with a number of items such that when the user checks the item in the drop down a description will appear on the side of the page. which tag in html allows me to create this description field that depends on the item in the drop down. Thank you

Comment: You will have to use more than just HTML for this. You need JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this only with HTML, you have to use some CSS and Javascript to achieve this... you can use the CSS property `display` to `show / hide` the description box and javascript `onchange` function to check when an option in a drop down box is selected / changed..

Comment: i know i will need javascript and css but i just need to know what can i use as a container to show and hide the info in when i click. Thank you